# О стилистической корректности предложения

Tags: грамматика, стилистика

**Из статьи** [Вильфанд спрогнозировал рост числа «барических депрессий» в октябре](https://pogoda.mail.ru/news/57943599/)

*По словам Вильфанда, «барические депрессии» приносят, прежде всего, ненастную погоду и похолодания. Самым «депрессивным» месяцем является ноябрь.*

Есть ли здесь **стилистические** ошибки и как записать **правильно**?

Comment: Не знаю, что такое "барические депрессии", но, наверно, вызывают, а не приносят.

Comment: С лексикой да, проблемы, но, кажется, и с грамматикой тоже)

Comment: Не вижу. А именно?

Comment: Может, я ошибаюсь, и все нормально)

Comment: Ну так скажите, проверю.

Comment: Кстати, в вашей фразе "может" общее. Разделение не получается: *Может, я ошибаюсь. И всё нормально.* Обе части под сомнением. Интересный момент.

Comment: Кстати, грамматические ошибки не относятся к стилистическим. https://blog.selfpub.ru/booksmistakes

Comment: «Может, я ошибАюсь, и (тогда) все (там) нормАльно)». Два сообщения, причинно-следственная связь

Comment: У Розенталя грамматика присутствует-таки в его книге СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/20.htm   Я имею в виду стилистическую грамматику.

Comment: "Тогда" нельзя опускать, с "тогда" уже делится: *Может, я ошибаюсь. И тогда всё нормально.* Если строго, то в первой части вероятность, нет ситуации, нет когда, нет если. Буквально: *Возможна ошибка, и тогда всё нормально.* Эта структура не очень правильная. По ударениям можно выбирать, только если оба варианта корректны! Ну естественно, исправление грамматических ошибок тоже входит в литературное редактирование. Вот ваша стилистическая грамматика: https://studfile.net/preview/4384937/page:4/ Не вижу здесь никаких специфических форм.